# ESLint: how to sort import members with eslint-plugin-import?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm trying to add the sorting of import members such as this rule in [sort-member](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/sort-imports#ignoremembersort).

However, since I'm already using [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/tree/v2.25.3), there is a conflict because each of these rules is trying to sort imports based on different parameters:

- `sort-member` sorts following the order `["none", "all", "multiple", "single"]`, depending on how many imports there is from one module
- `eslint-plugin-import` sorts following the order `["builtin", "external", "parent", "sibling", "index"]`, depending on the type of import

Is there a way to only use the member sort of `sort-member` (== ignore the `memberSyntaxSortOrder` rule), or is there a feature similar to [memberSort](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/sort-imports#ignoremembersort) built in `eslint-plugin-import`?

All I'm trying to do is to have an error for:

```js
import { b, a, c } from 'foo.js'
```

And have it automatically fixed to:

```js
import { a, b, c } from 'foo.js'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution by myself: despite `memberSyntaxSortOrder` being mandatory and only accepting an array, you can actually ignore this rule by simply using the `ignoreDeclarationSort` rule, set to `true`.

So to make `sort/import` work with an alphabetical order of multiple import lines, simply add in your rule block:

```
'sort-imports': [
  'error',
  {
    ignoreDeclarationSort: true,
  },
],
```